# std::initializer_list<T> as constructor parameter and uniform initialization syntax

Tags: qt, c++11, initializer-list, qvector, uniform-initialization

For some time now I use C++11 uniform initialization syntax `{}` to initialize all my variables.

Right now I want to initialize a `QVector<int>` **with a specific size**, so I need to call the `QVector(int size)` constructor (doc [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html)).

However, `QVector` also has the following constructor: 
`QVector(std::initializer_list<T> args)`

So when I initialize my variable like this: `QVector<int> foo{ 100 };`, it doesn't initialize my QVector with a *size* of *100* elements, but rather calls the other constructor which constructs a QVector **with** ***one*** **element of value** ***100***.

How can I call the `QVector(int size)` constructor **but still use the uniform initialization syntax**?

Comment: You should look at the type's constructors available. I just checked and    `inline QVector(std::initializer_list<T> args);` appears to be the only constructor supporting the syntax. Now try to understand what it does. What IS `std::initializer_list<T>`?? It looks to me being the way to pass some number of values of type T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do the thing which is impossible. The only way to get constructor with specific size is using `()` brackets:

```
QVector<int> v(100);
```

The reason is that otherwise it would cause ambiguity. Compiler would not know what is

```
QVector<int> v{100};
```

As it is done now, it always knows this is initializer list, i.e. inserts 1 element of 100, not 100 default elements.

Pay attention, this is not Qt-specific, in STL this works the same way.